# Loop Confusion Comparing Objects

Tags: powershell

I am trying to create my own service comparison script. I see some online but want to do this myself. I've only gotten so far. I keep getting confused.

The desired output is with the following format. It doesn't even have to show what's different. I just want to see what the previous state was compared to the current state. I did a compare-object and it didn't give me the format I desired. I then thought maybe I should just do two nested loops and create a new object with the states I want in it. It didn't work out correctly, it returns an array. So then I thought, maybe a for loop in the foreach loop... I keep confusing myself and it's so close.

You have to provide a csv with some services to compare to to make this work as part of it's paramaters.

**Usage**

```
Inspect-ServiceSnapshot -SnapshotPath "C:\YourPath"
```

**Desired output**

Name CurrentState PreviousState
app1 Running      Stopped

**Code So Far**

```
function Inspect-ServiceSnapshot {
[CmdletBinding()]
param (
    #Snapshot
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [ValidatePattern("C:")]
    [string]
    $SnapshotPath,

    # timer
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
    [int]
    $TimeToWait
)

   if($TimeToWait -ne $null) {
    Start-Sleep -Seconds $TimeToWait
    $list = @()
    $old = Import-Csv -Path $SnapshotPath
    foreach($entry in (get-service)) {
        foreach($oldItem in $old) {
            $object = New-Object -TypeName psobject -Property @{
                Name = $entry.Name
                CurrentStatus = $entry.status
                DisplayName = $entry.displayname
                PreviousStatus = $oldItem.status
        }
        $list += $object
        }
    }
    $list

} else {
    $list = @()
    $old = Import-Csv -Path $SnapshotPath
    foreach($entry in (get-service)) {
        foreach($oldItem in $old) {
            $object = New-Object -TypeName psobject -Property @{
                Name = $entry.Name
                CurrentStatus = $entry.status
                DisplayName = $entry.displayname
                PreviousStatus = $oldItem.status
        }
        $list += $object
        }
    }
    $list
}
```

}

Comment: Why do you repeat the exact same code block in the `else` ? Just use it once with `if($TimeToWait) { Start-Sleep -Seconds $TimeToWait }` on top. Also, you are creating an object with `$entry.status` and next you set property `PreviousStatus` to some service you read sequantially from a CSV file. Are you talking about the SAME service there?

Comment: Yes, it should be the same service. All of this is so that I can satisfy a request of me. They want it to be in a table like format that has column headers of Service Name, Current State, and Previous State for each service. They want to see if anything changes as a troubleshooting tool.

Comment: Thanks on the if statement. I thought the whole block wouldn't run if it equated to true

Comment: Ok, I understand, but in your code you do nothing to check if the service you take from the `$old` csv file is in fact the same service you see in the `$entry`. This way, you are writing the old status of a service and the new status of another service.

Comment: So I should put an if condition to check and then run?

Comment: You do not show the CSV for `$old`, but assuming this has the same fields as the properties you collect in the psobject, I would not do the `foreach($oldItem in $old) {...}` at all. Instead get the previous item doing somethiong like this: `$oldItem = $old | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq $entry.Name }`. Then build your PSObject

Comment: Thank you for you input!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it because it is actually checking the value for the old service to be the same as the one `Get-Service` provides at a certain time.

```
function Inspect-ServiceSnapshot {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        #Snapshot
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [ValidateScript({Test-Path $_ -PathType Leaf})]
        [string]$SnapshotPath,

        # timer
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
        [int]$TimeToWait = 0
    )

    if($TimeToWait) { Start-Sleep -Seconds $TimeToWait }

    $list = @()
    $old = Import-Csv -Path $SnapshotPath
    foreach($entry in (Get-Service)) {
        # make sure we are dealing with the SAME service
        $oldItem = $old | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq $entry.Name }
        $object = New-Object -TypeName psobject -Property @{
            Name = $entry.Name
            CurrentStatus = $entry.status
            DisplayName = $entry.displayname
            PreviousStatus = if ($oldItem) { $oldItem.status } else { 'Unknown' }
        }

        $list += $object
    }

    $list
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer is assuming there are no new services added on a regular basis.

You almost got it! You can forgo the nested loops, get rid of the else block (it is redundant), and use an index loop. When you're using nested loops like that, you are iterating through all of the array elements in the $old array every time you iterate through one of the (get-service) objects. This can cause issues when your arrays include thousands of objects.

You can easily get to what you want by using a for loop.

e.g.

```
if($TimeToWait -ne $null) {
Start-Sleep -Seconds $TimeToWait
}
$list = @();
$old = Import-Csv -Path $SnapshotPath | Sort-Object Name;
$new = Get-Service | Sort-Object Name;
for ($i -eq 0; $i -lt $old.length -or $i -lt $new.length; $i++) {
    $object = New-Object -TypeName psobject -Property @{
    Name = $new[$i].Name
    CurrentStatus = $new[$i].status
    DisplayName = $new[$i].displayname
    PreviousStatus = $old[$i].status
    }
$list += $object;
} 
$list;
```

A lot of your code is redundant and you can just do this all in one go. Since you're not technically comparing any objects, you can just populate the fields as they go.

Comment: Thank you for the input! I knew a for loop was the best way to go but had no clue you could put the || in the statement! ($i -eq 0; $i -lt $old.length || $new.length; $i++)

Comment: @Sanwil9 no problem, hope that helps. You can put most  operators in an expression.

Comment: That still does not account for the fact that `Get-Service` may come up with new services that were not in the old CSV file. This again does NOT check if the service is the same one. Also, there are typos in the code: `$enew` and `||`

Comment: Actually, the || isn't working. Lol is it my version ps?

Comment: @Theo thanks for that, I had to switch out of JavaScript mindset :) edited. Also, this is assuming that there are no new services added on a regular basis. Services are mostly static when compared to processes. Comparing processes are a different story since they’re more dynamic.

Comment: I can add an if conditional statement to check

Comment: @Sanwil9 just edited the code, was using a different syntax since I was working on a JavaScript project recently .

Comment: i think you'll have to type out the full comparison again. like `$i -lt $old.length -or $i -lt $new.length` because i get `$true` for this `2 -lt 3 -and 1`

Comment: @PeterKay _Services are mostly static_, but there is no telling when the previous CSV was created and when this function runs. Many services may have started or shut down in the meantime, so sorry, but that is bogus..

Comment: @Theo thanks for the input! Static in terms of services normally do not get removed or added as frequently as processes. The answer still compares last known state. Your solution provides name checking so OP can use that as well, as there are less room for errors. Appreciate the feed back!